# Global Setup/Teardown for NUnit

Tags: c#, nunit-3.0

I have to use a library, which must be initialized before the first usage and shutdown after the last usage. To make the things more complicated the library does not allow to initialize again, after the shutdown. So, after calling `Shutdown()` the library is dead for the remaining process lifetime.

For the application this is not an issue, since here I have deterministic entry and exit points. But I now facing issues with unit-tests in NUnit.

While I try to mock out as much as possible from this library, I still have some tests distributed in different assemblies, which needs to use this library.

If the test would just be in a single assembly, I could use `OneTimeSetUp` and `OneTimeTearDown` for this (without namespace). However, this does not work for the seconds assembly, since this is not calling the OneTimeSetup from the other assembly and I cannot have an own OneTimeSetUp here, since then the library is two times setup and shutdown, which does not work with this library.

I also cannot combine all related tests into a single assembly, because this makes semantically no sense (in the one assembly there are test-cases for generic code, which should be reused in different applications, while the other assembly contains application specific test-cases).

Is there any "process wide" Setup/Teardown, which works across different namespaces and assemblies?

Comment: Look at [Prefer helper methods to setup and teardown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-best-practices#prefer-helper-methods-to-setup-and-teardown)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Thanks for your answer. However, I don't really understand why suggesting this? As I wrote in my question, I'm aware of setup and teardown methods in NUnit, but those I can find in the documentation don't fit to my needs. If you can point me to those setup/teardown methods, that are responsible for the whole test process, I would be very happy to use them.